# Prevent escaping slashes in url helpers (specifically when called using .send() to url_helpers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Perhaps the title of this question is cryptic, but the problem is real, I've just upgraded an application from Rails 3 to 4 and encountered the following issue (on both Ruby 2.0 and 2.1):

I have a method which calls several url helpers in a loop, using send(), like this:

```
class Sitemap
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  #...
  # regions = [:city, :county, :zip]
  regions.each do |region|
    url_params = ... # [name, additional_id]
    send("#{region}_url", url_params)
  end
```

In Rails 3 the above resulted in urls like http://example.com/cities/atlanta/2

In Rails 4 I get http://example.com/cities/atlanta%2f2

slash gets CGI escaped, I don't want this. I use it in generating sitemap XML for my site and it seems to work even if the forward slash is escaped, but it looks ugly and I don't know if it will work correctly for all bots or clients.

UPDATE: after some debugging I've found out that the CGI escaping occurs somewhere in ActionDispatch::Journey::Visitors::Formatter

```
Router::Utils.escape_segment() # method call somewhere in 
ActionDispatch::Journey::Visitors::Formatter # during
Visitors::Formatter.new(path_options).accept(path.spec) # in
@set.formatter.generate(:path_info, named_route, options, recall, PARAMETERIZE) # in a call to
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Generator#generate
```

Comment: It seems that it's caused by the Router::Utils.escape_segment() method call somewhere in ActionDispatch::Journey::Visitors::Formatter , during   Visitors::Formatter.new(path_options).accept(path.spec)   in   @set.formatter.generate(:path_info, named_route, options, recall, PARAMETERIZE)   in a call to ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Generator#generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with escaping slashes when generating the URL, here's the change:

```
# from:
send(region_url, url_params)
# to:
send(region_url, { id: url_params[0], market_id: url_params[1]})
# sometimes url_params is a one element array
```

The key is to provide a hash of parameters with explicitly assigned keys and values.

I use send to dynamically call method (xxx_url) from url_helpers module which is included in my model. url_params array looks like ['some-slug', 12]

Comment: What you arrived at is probably the best solution for clarity and consistency. I think array explosion would also have worked here (```send(region_url, *url_params)```) but it's less obvious what the intent is written that way.